# Как сделать разметку как у инстаграма?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

У меня есть изображения, расположенные по три в ряд, после третьего стоит тег `<br>`.

размер изображения:

```
width:32%;
height:32%;
```

когда уменьшаю окно браузера, они пропорционально уменьшаются.

как сделать так, чтобы они всегда оставались квадратными, как у *инстаграма*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может такой вариант подойдет?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.wrap > div {    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    width: 31%;
    padding-bottom: 31%;
    margin: 1%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.wrap > div img {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6q1q2zkh/)

или так

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap{
    text-align: center;    
    font-size: 0;
}
.wrap img {    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 31%;
    padding-bottom: 31%;
    margin: 1%;    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/q5kqbyz9/)

Answer (score 1):

Убрать высоту. Ну или сделать её auto.